# Show a div on click with cuepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

Why won't this work?

Using *cuepoint.js*; you can define cue points within the html5 video.
But; I'd like to; in addition display a #div on click. And ONLY on click.
Once the video resumes; or the image is clicked again; the video resumes and the #div will **disappear**!!!!

```
   #playdiv1 {
        display: none;
    }
```

---

```
$('#1').click(function() { 
  cuepoint.setTime(1)();
  $("playdiv1").style.display = "block"; // Why wont this work?
});
```

---

This div should show along with the que:

```
<div id="playdiv1" style="min-height: 300px; min-width: 500px; display: hidden;">

</div>
```

**Library in reference;**
http://cuepoint.org/

FULL CODE ~
http://pastebin.com/HG0wVVaK

**This doesn't make sense.** THE cuepoint time; works..

```
$('#1').click(function(){ 
  cuepoint.setTime(0)();
```

**But when I add the '$('#playdiv1').show();' right underneath it. It doesn't work?**

```
$('#1').click(function(){ 
  cuepoint.setTime(0)();
  $('#playdiv1').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Switching the order somehow worked;**

```
$('#1').click(function(){ 
  $('#playdiv1').show();
   cuepoint.setTime(0)(); // Having this at the bottom; or after the show.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong.

Your code, `$("playdiv1")`, matches elements of type `<playdiv1></playdiv1>`, which isn't what you want.

The correct code, `$("#playdiv1")`, selects the element with *id* `playdiv1`.

You're also attempting to set the `style` attribute on the jQuery wrapper around the element. You need to either use the `.show` method, or access the first matched element.

Either of these will work:

```
$('#playdiv1').show();

// or

$('#playdiv1')[0].style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Meagar. Doesn't work dude. I've justed updated my Q with a pastebin of my full code via last attempt. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the CSS hiding the playdiv1 you do not need a display declaration inline with your HTML, so remove that -

```
<div id="playdiv1" style="min-height: 300px; min-width: 500px;">
```

and change the jQuery to

```
$('#playdiv1').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this...

```
$('#1').on('click', function() { 
  cuepoint.setTime(1)();
  $("#playdiv1").show();
});
```

And remove `display: hidden;` of the style property in the `<div>` tag...